# how do i prove this equality as a statment about parallelograms?

Tags: calculus, vectors

how do i prove this as a statement about parallelograms step by step?
let's say we have to vectors x and y, i know that x+y equals the diagonal the two vectors form and x-y equals the smaller diagonal that the two vectors from?
i thin i should start by square rooting everything but then i get stuck because i don't know how to get rid of the absolute values?

$$|x + y|^2 + |x - y|^2 = 2|x|^2 + 2|y|^2$$

Comment: What is that funny symbol in $x-y$? Do you understand the dot product and its properties, especially that $|\overrightarrow u|^2=\overrightarrow u\cdot \overrightarrow u$? The problem is very easy if you do.

Comment: if you do x dot y, that would be (x(1) * x(2)) + (y(1) * y(2)), here we have x+y and x-y not x+x and y+y

Comment: You need more general properties than that. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will use these facts about the dot product for vectors $a,b,c$:

$$|a|^2=a\cdot a$$
$$a\cdot(b\pm c)=a\cdot b\pm a\cdot c$$
$$(a\pm b)\cdot c=a\cdot c\pm b\cdot c$$

Then

$$\begin{align}
|x+y|^2 + |x-y|^2&= (x+y) \cdot (x+y) + (x-y) \cdot (x-y)\\[2 ex]
 &= x\cdot (x+y) + y\cdot (x+y) + x\cdot (x-y) - y\cdot (x-y)\\[2 ex]
 &= x\cdot x+ x\cdot y + y\cdot x+ y\cdot y + x\cdot x- x\cdot y - y\cdot x+ y\cdot y \\[2 ex]
 &= 2x\cdot x+2y\cdot y \\[2 ex]
 &= 2|x|^2+2|y|^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you, it took me a while to see what you did, for me the most difficult part is knowing what the first step is.